# Highchart basic chart using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

I'm triying to make a highcharts graph in nodejs, i already installed it via npm. 
I'm trying with a basic chart, but it give me this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
    at /opt/node/project/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:9:325
    at /opt/node/project/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js:27:171
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/node/project/actions/mailrequest.js:3:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
```

Here is my code, this is in a js:

```
  var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: htmldata
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [htmldata]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [htmldata]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [htmldata]
    }]

});
```

I searched for this and apparently is because node, but i'm not sure, this is quite unusual.

Hope you can help. Thanks.
And if you are by, can you help me to send such graphic via email, i'm able to send a basic mail, but i want to send the chart.
I already have an array to make the graph. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what version of Node and Highcharts?

Comment: Basically, Highcharts is a browser chart library - so it requires DOM to be able to generate a chart. Unless you use some kind of DOM implementation in node (e.g. jsdom) you wont be able to create a chart. However, you can use exporting API and send the options from the server - see docs here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview You can also use node epxorting server https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time answering a SO question, but I managed to solve the issue 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined' while creating a basic chart from the Highcharts website. I followed @morganfree instructions 'Basically, Highcharts is a browser chart library - so it requires DOM to be able to generate a chart. Unless you use some kind of DOM implementation in node (e.g. jsdom) you wont be able to create a chart. '. Keep in mind this works for the most basic chart implementation. You may need to dive deeper into jsdom for other types of charts.

Steps to solve:

1. Download the npm node-jsdom package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsdom
2. Paste this code into the main file that you run to start your program.

   ```
   const jsdom = require("node-jsdom");

   jsdom.env(
     "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js",
     ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
     function (errors, window) {
       console.log("there have been", window.$("a").length, "nodejs 
     releases!");
   }
   );
   ```
3. Follow steps 1 & 2 in this link - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart
4. re-render your html page and you should see the default chart that Hghcharts provides. :D Hope this helped.

PS. read up on the node-jsdom docs to see what the code snippet does.